# Embedding Youtube functionality in Qt

Tags: javascript, qt, youtube-api, qtwebengine

I want to embed `youtube` functionality in my `Qt` GUI Application.

I've checked the [youtubeview example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitqml-youtubeview-example.html) of `Qt` but it does not work, because (I believe&assume) they used the `Youtube Data API v2` and URLs are not valid anymore.

Is it feasible to do this in `Qt`? Could someone provide a minimal sample code for `Qt`, (if possible for `QML`)?

Comment: Which Qt you have? I can open youtube links correctly with Qt5.5.1 and latest QtWebKit version.

Comment: I have the same version [Qt-5.5.1]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you enabled plugins like this: QWebSettings *defaultSettings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);

Comment: No, can you do it also in QML? And what's the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is a YouTube Played component available with V-Play. There is an example that uses poth the player API and the YouTube Data API: https://v-play.net/updates/release-2-18-1-javascript-promises-for-rest-services-tinder-swipe-material-cards-qml-qsortfilterproxymodel-qml-youtube-player

Minimum example for the player:

```
import VPlayApps 1.0

App {
  NavigationStack {
    Page {
      title: "YouTube Player"

      YouTubeWebPlayer {
        videoId: "KQgqTYCfJjM"
        autoplay: true
      }

    }
  }
}
```